# How to do field update basedon approval action?

Tags: approval-process

I have a requirement that admin sholud Approve/Reject an approval request submitted by a user and after clicking the Approve button a field should be updated in that object in which the approval process has been created.How to do that?

Comment: What uou have tried so far? Where you are stuck?

Comment: To add to @SantanuBoral comment, have you gone through the Trailhead [Lightning Flow Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation) or looked in Salesforce Help where I know this topic is covered?